# Make Legend dot larger

Tags: plotting, legending

I am having trouble making the dot marker for Cosec(x) larger. The plot points should be size 1% but the legend marker is super tiny and I don't know how to make it larger.

```
ClearAll[x]
g1 = Plot[Sin[x], {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thick, Dashed], PlotLegends -> {"Sin(x)"}, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}, Ticks -> {{-3 Pi, -2 Pi, -Pi, 0, Pi, 2 Pi, 3 Pi}, {-3, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3}}];
ClearAll[x]; x = Table[{x, Csc[x]}, {x, -3 Pi, 3 Pi, 0.1}];
g2 = ListPlot[x, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize -> 0.01], PlotLegends -> {"Cosec(x)"}];
Show[g1, g2, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

For clarity, here is the assignment question:

"Graded exercise 1: On the same graph, plot two functions, sin(x) and cosec(x) on the interval [-3[Pi],3[Pi]]. The function sin(x) should be plotted as a thick dashed black line and cosec(x) should be plotted as red points, with horizontal distance between points of 0.1; point size 1% of the total size. Label the horizontal axis "x" and the vertical axis "y". Provide an appropriate legend and choose an appropriate vertical range. [20%]"

Comment: Employing an example from the docs of `PlotLegends`: `legend = Grid[{{Graphics[{Red, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.1]}, ImageSize -> 5], 
     "Cosec(x)"}}];
g2 = ListPlot[x, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize -> 0.01], 
   PlotLegends -> legend];`

Comment: Try `PlotLegends -> 
 SwatchLegend[{"Cosec(x)"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, 
  LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]` instead of  `PlotLegends -> {"Cosec(x)"}`?

Comment: I think this is a good question. the expectation is that there is some simple option to adapt the `LegendMarkerSize`. It seems from the two previous comments that this is may not be the case. Instead on has to either create a `Graphics` object oneself or use `SwatchLegend`. Both routes are more complicated than expected and hard to find via the help search function. (I had this problem under time pressure once and I couldn't sort it in Mathematica.)

Comment: @kglr How'd you find out about that `"Bubble"` option?  It's not in the documentation.

Comment: @tparker, it is mentioned in [SwatchLegend >> Options >> LegendMarkers](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SwatchLegend.html). You can get other built-in markers using `ChartElementData[SwatchLegend]`.

Comment: @kglr Ah, thanks so much.  I was looking in the documentation for `LegendMarkers` instead of `SwatchLegend`.

Answer (score 6):

Using `SwatchLegend[{"Cosec(x)"}, LegendMarkerSize -> 20, LegendMarkers -> "Bubble"]` as the setting for `PlotLegends` in `g2`:

```
g2 = ListPlot[x, PlotStyle -> Directive[Red, PointSize -> 0.01], 
  PlotLegends-> SwatchLegend[{"Cosec(x)"}, LegendMarkerSize->20, LegendMarkers->"Bubble"]];

Show[g1, g2, AxesLabel -> {"x", "y"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]